# Drawable from String in Android

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

How do I get a Drawable resource if I have the String (its name) as it appears in the drabale folder?

```
int categoryPicIndex = myCursor.getColumnIndex(CookingContract.CategoryEntry.COLUMN_PIC_CATEGORY);
String categoryPic = myCursor.getString(categoryPicIndex);
```

At this point I have the string that I would use to call **R.drawable.___** .
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `"yourImageView"` is the ImageView and you want to set background of it and the name of image is `"imageName"`

```
yourImageView.setImageResource(context.getResources().
                getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null,context.getPackageName()));
```

But i should say sorry as it doesn't really give you drawable  but it gives Resource, But i hope this will help you use the string name of drawable file.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this uses reflection, so it's preferable to reference R.drawable.my_drawable directly (if this is an option)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I used: int drawableResource = myContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+ categoryPic, null, myContext.getPackageName());

Comment: Better to use this way or to save the pics as BLOB in the DB?

Comment: fractalwrench  but what if you have string name not the R.drawable.my_drawable?

Comment: i use this method when i am not sure which image i will be using in the view , i dont really bother to get into DB for this simple thing

Comment: Just save image in  drawable folder   use this method, i think it is simpler is not it ?